# cakePHP3 prefix routing and same name for controller / subcontroller

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.0

I have (more precisely "want") the following structure and i try to build the routes:

```
src/Controller/OrdersController.php
src/Controller/Orders/PositionsController.php
```

So the routes are:

```
/orders > OrdersController
/orders/details/1 > OrdersController:details
/orders/positions/details/1 > PositionsController:details
```

The solution is prefix routing, so far, so good. But it only works with fixed routes before the prefix routing.

So this works:

```
Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes)
{
    $routes->connect('/orders/details/*', [
        'controller' => 'Orders',
        'action' => 'details'
    ]);
    $routes->prefix('orders', function (RouteBuilder $routes)
    {
        $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
    });    
    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
});
```

But I want it more flexible and don't define every route. Can i use the ":action" flag to define the routes.

Best case would be to have multiple level like:

```
src/Controller/OrdersController.php
src/Controller/Orders/PositionsController.php
src/Controller/Orders/Positions/CommentsController.php
```

Is it possible?
This would be more "structure" instead of OrdersController, OrdersPositionsController and OrdersPositionsCommentsController, ...

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it by myself:

```
Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes)
{
    $routes->prefix('orders', [], function (RouteBuilder $routes)
    {
        // -- order positions
        $routes->connect('/positions', [
            'controller' => 'Positions',
            'action' => 'index'
        ]);
        $routes->connect('/positions/:action/*', [
            'controller' => 'Positions'
        ]);

        $routes->prefix('positions', [], function (RouteBuilder $routes)
        {
            $routes->connect('/comments', [
                'controller' => 'Comments',
                'action' => 'index'
            ]);
        });

    });

    $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);

});
```